# Generate generic CRUD operations[insert,delete,update] with Slick

Tags: scala, slick

I'm new to Slick.I wanted to know how to generate generic SQL queries in scala using Slick
This is my sample code in scala for generic insert operation using jdbc,
Want to use slick for the same :

```
    def insert(connection: Connection,
          tableName: String,
          columnList: List[String],
          valueList: List[Any]): Option[Int] = {

        try {
          val query = queryBuilderInsert(tableName, columnList)
          val pst = connection.prepareStatement(query)
          if (valueList.nonEmpty) {
            for { i <- 1 to valueList.size } {
              pst.setObject(i, valueList(i - 1))
            }
          }
          Some(pst.executeUpdate())
        } catch {
          case e: Exception =>
            // Exception Handling
            None
        }
      }
def queryBuilderInsert(tableName: String,columnList: List[String]): String= {
    val paramList = new ListBuffer[String]
    val query = new StringBuilder("insert into " + tableName + "(")

    if (columnList.nonEmpty) {
      for { i <- 1 to columnList.size } {
        query.append(columnList(i - 1))
        if (i != columnList.size) {
          query.append(comma)
        }
        else {
          query.append(") values(")
        }
      }
    }

    if (columnList.nonEmpty) {
      for { i <- 1 to columnList.size } {
        paramList.append(questionMark)
      }
      query.append(paramList.mkString(comma) + ")")
    }
    query.toString()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider [ActiveSlick](http://www.strongtyped.io/active-slick/). It does exactly what you need: it wraps models and inject CRUD operations based on a ID and gives you all the utilities to insert, upsert, delete and retrieve your entities.

Comment: But we still need to know the table[entity structure] beforehand, and the inserts are specific to table i.e. insert into a particular entity

Comment: But this is not the case, the table name will be provided a run tym, so the table structure is not known. I want to build a generic insert which takes up table names,column list to which values are inserted and the values to be inserted.

So,Active slick doesn't fulfill, correct if I'm wrong